# How to solve in Ionic app “Your APK's version code needs to be higher than 20000”

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Can anybody please help me out with this one? Google's response, when I uploaded the app, was:

“Apache Cordova:
The vulnerabilities were fixed in Apache Cordova v.4.1.1 or higher.

You can find information about how to upgrade in this Google Help Center article.

APK Version(s): 20000“

I don't know if this is of any help, but the app runs on:

- The app is build in Ionic/html style
- Cordova CLI version: 6.4.0
- Android version 6.0.0
- Node Version: v4.4.2
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0

So if anyone has any idea what should I change, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the entire message? Difficult to figure out with just one line..

Comment: That was the whole message, that is why I couldn't figured it out. Thomas's answer was the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten this error when attempting to change the version number of my application in the config file. You need to make sure you change the `<widget>` version number instead of the `<xml>` version number.

This is wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.2.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.url.name" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App Name</name>
```

But this is correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.url.name" version="1.2.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App Name</name>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: OMG yes, that was it! Thank you so much! It really was the problem in that last digit of the app version.